# adding and subtracting from a date

Tags: python

I'm passing an argument into a script that's providing the date in the following format -

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

How do I then convert that value to either subtract or add a day?

snippet -

```
script.py 2014-12-15

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("date", help="date to check dependencies")
args = parser.parse_args()

date = args.date
date1 = date - 1
date2 = date + 1
```

I need this because I'll then be calling an sql query that will use both values to do the search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can parse the string `'2014-12-15'` using [datetime.datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
In [184]: import datetime as DT
In [185]: DT.datetime.strptime('2014-12-15', '%Y-%m-%d')
Out[185]: datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 15, 0, 0)
```

Note that `argparse` has a [`type` keyword parameter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#type) which allows you to convert the argument strings to the desired type:

```
parser.add_argument(
    "date"
    , type=lambda x: DT.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d')
    , help="date to check dependencies")
```

so that `args.date` will be a [datetime.datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects), provided the user supplies a valid date.

You can then add or subtract a [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) to find the desired dates:

```
In [186]: DT.datetime(2014, 12, 15, 0, 0) + DT.timedelta(days=1)
Out[186]: datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 16, 0, 0)
```

---

```
import argparse
import datetime as DT

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "date"
    , type=lambda x: DT.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d')
    , help="date to check dependencies")
args = parser.parse_args()

date = args.date
one_day = DT.timedelta(days=1)
date1 = date - one_day
date2 = date + one_day
print(date1)
print(date2)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Didn't realize I'd have to do the conversion in there.

Answer (score 0):

`date` is a string at that moment, what you need is a way to convert to a Date. You can do this using the Dateutil:

```
import datetime
import dateutil.parser

dt = dateutil.parser.parse(date)
```

Next, you can add and subtract days:

```
dt2 = dt+timedelta(days=1)
```

and write out:

```
str(dt2)
```